# Navigation drawer with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, navigation-drawer

I am tyring to make a time table . In which Navigation drawer will show days and tab bar will show timing wise lunch, dinner, breakfast.

Question : How to make conditions such that we get to know about both the selected navigation drawer item and selected tab item at same time .

**MessActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mess);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    tabsPager tabsPager = new tabsPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPager);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));

    tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorAccent));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorAccent));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                }
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                }
            } else {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorPrimary));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorPrimary));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.monday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.tuesday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.wednesday) {
    } else if (id == R.id.thursday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.friday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.saturday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.sunday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.next) {

    } else if (id == R.id.today) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**tabsPager.java**

```
public class tabsPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


String[] titles=new String[]{"Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner"};

public tabsPager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            BreakfastFragment breakfastFragment =new BreakfastFragment();

            return  breakfastFragment;
        case 1: LunchFragment lunchFragment =new LunchFragment();
            return lunchFragment;
        case 2:
            DinnerFragment dinnerFragment =new DinnerFragment();
            return dinnerFragment;



    }
    return  null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

EDIT
MessActivity

```
public class MessActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
public static int selectedNavigationMenuID= 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mess);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    tabsPager tabsPager = new tabsPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPager);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));

    tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorAccent));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorAccent));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                }





            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                }
            } else {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorPrimary));
                tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                        R.color.colorPrimary));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean  onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    selectedNavigationMenuID=item.getItemId();
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.next)
    {

    }
    else if(id==R.id.today){}

    else if (id == R.id.monday) { }
    else if (id == R.id.tuesday) { }
    else if (id == R.id.wednesday) {}
    else if (id == R.id.thursday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.friday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.saturday) {

    } else if (id == R.id.sunday) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


}
```

tabsPager

```
  public tabsPager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}





@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
}


public void set(int selectedNavigationMenuID) { MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID = selectedNavigationMenuID; }



@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {



        case 0:set(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID);
            BreakfastFragment breakfastFragment=new BreakfastFragment();
            return breakfastFragment;
        case 1:set(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID);
            LunchFragment lunchFragment=new LunchFragment();
            return lunchFragment;
        case 2:set(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID);
            DinnerFragment dinnerFragment=new DinnerFragment();
            return dinnerFragment;
    }
    return  null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

BreakFastFragment

```
public class BreakfastFragment extends Fragment {


public BreakfastFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_breakfast, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) inf.findViewById(R.id.breakfast_textview_id);
    if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==0)
    {

        tv.setText("now");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==1)
    {
        tv.setText("B_today");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==2)
    {
        tv.setText("B_monday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==3)
    {
        tv.setText("B-tuesday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==4)
    {
        tv.setText("B-wednesday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==5)
    {
        tv.setText("B-thursday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==6)
    {
        tv.setText("b-friday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==7)
    {
        tv.setText("b-saturday");}
    else if(MessActivity.selectedNavigationMenuID==8)
    {
        tv.setText("b-sunday");}

    return inf;



}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tabs Selected Item it is simple use `viewpager.getCurrentItem()` 
but to get the selected item of `navigationview` there are two ways

1. Use a global variable to hold the id

   ```
   public class MessActivity extends AppCompatActivityimplements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
   public static int selectedNavigationMenuID= 0; //assuming the first item will be selected by default.
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       selectedNavigationMenuID=item.getItemId();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Use a method that will return the selected position from the navigationView

   ```
   private int getCheckedItem(NavigationView navigationView) {
   Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
   for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
       MenuItem item = menu.getIndex(i);
       if (item.isChecked()) {
           return i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
   }
   ```

---

Here comes the new code

**Activity**

```
    public class MessActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tablayout;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private String selectedNavMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mess);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        selectedNavMenu = "Monday" ;//setting default value
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), selectedNavMenu);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout));
        tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorAccent));
                    }
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                                android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    }
                } else {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    tablayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MessActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    }
                }
                //Here so that even if ur fragment is regenerated you get the latest value of the selectedNavigationItem
                mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedNavMenu);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        selectedNavMenu = (String) item.getTitle();
        //Just so that new created fragment will get the latest value
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.selectedNavigationMenuText = selectedNavMenu;
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedNavMenu);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

SparseArray<PlaceholderFragment> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>();
String selectedNavigationMenuText;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String selectedNavigationMenuText) {
    super(fm);
    this.selectedNavigationMenuText = selectedNavigationMenuText;
}

@Override
public PlaceholderFragment getItem(int position) {
    try {
        if (sparseArray.valueAt(position) != null) {
            return sparseArray.get(position);
        } else {
            PlaceholderFragment placeHolderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, selectedNavigationMenuText);
            sparseArray.put(position, placeHolderFragment);
            return placeHolderFragment;
        }
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        PlaceholderFragment placeHolderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, selectedNavigationMenuText);
        sparseArray.put(position, placeHolderFragment);
        return placeHolderFragment;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private static final String SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selectedTab";
private int selecteTabItem;
private TextView textView;
private String selectedMenuItem;

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, String selectedNavigationItem) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    args.putString(SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, selectedNavigationItem);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mess, container, false);
    textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    selecteTabItem = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    selectedMenuItem = getArguments().getString(SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM);
    setText();
    return rootView;
}

private void setText() {
    switch (selecteTabItem) {
        case 0:
            textView.setText("BREAKFAST : " + selectedMenuItem);
            break;
        case 1:
            textView.setText("LUNCH : " + selectedMenuItem);
            break;
        case 2:
            textView.setText("DINNER : " + selectedMenuItem);
            break;

    }
}

public void setSelectedNavigationItem(String selectedMenuItem) {
    this.selectedMenuItem = selectedMenuItem;
    setText();
}
}
```

---

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Inside OnTabSelected  method , adding viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); solved the problem